# Map Brick Procedure Texture onto Correctly Scaled Models

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have modeled a floor plane. My setting uses metric, so all
units are in meters. In blender, 1 unit is equal to 1 metre.
I need to now create a tile texture for it which is
300 X 300 millimeters, using the brick procedure texture node
on the Node editor.

How can I make sure that the brick procedure texture will match
the 300 millimeter tile on my scaled model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order to get the right dimension for your tile material onto the UVW map.

1 . Use UV Project From View, while in top view.
2 . If your object is a wall then you will need to use the front, left or right view.
3.  Select "**Orthographic**" option in the tool panel ...
4.  This will match your object you have modelled to scale.
5.  These are the brick procedure texture settings

```
      a. Offset 0.00  
      b. Frequency 1.0 
      c. Squash 1.0  
      d. Frequency 1.0  
      e. Scale 1.0  
      f. Mortar Size 0.002  
      g. Bias 1.0  
      h. Brick Width 0.300 (In metres)  
      i. Brick Height 0.300 (In metres)
```

0.3 metres is exactly 300 millimetres.

---

**EXTRA NOTES**

> It is important to note that if you have accidentally/intentionally scale up
>   or down your object in Object Mode, you will be required to apply scale before
>   attempting the UV Unwrap of the model as incorrect scale will interfer with the 
>   unwrap.